# There is no com.inprise.vbroker.IIOP.Task in vbjclientorb.jar for AIX

Tags: java, corba

We are migrating to VisiBroker 7.0.   In our client application we started to use VBJ Client Runtime provided as a Java archive `vbjclientorb.jar` file.

There is no `com.inprise.vbroker.IIOP.Task` in `vbjclientorb.jar` for AIX.
But `com.inprise.vbroker.IIOP.Connection` class located in `vbjclientorb.jar` uses `com.inprise.vbroker.IIOP.Task` class.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.inprise.vbroker.IIOP.Task
        at com.inprise.vbroker.IIOP.Connection.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.inprise.vbroker.GIOP.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.inprise.vbroker.GIOP.OutputStream.writeUnfragmented(Unknown Source)
        at com.inprise.vbroker.GIOP.OutputStream.writeFragmented(Unknown Source)
        at com.inprise.vbroker.GIOP.Message.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.inprise.vbroker.GIOP.GiopConnection.send_message(Unknown Source)
        at com.inprise.vbroker.GIOP.GiopConnection.send_message(Unknown Source)
        at com.inprise.vbroker.GIOP.ProtocolConnector.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.inprise.vbroker.orb.DelegateImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Is it a bug?
Or we should include some additional jar?

Answer (score 0):

You must add vbjorb.jar to your classpath also.